# httpd.conf changes to allow www.mysite.com and www.mysite.com/mantis and phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I've got a php application which I use to place in:

```
~/public_html/beta/
```

And mantis and phpmyadmin in:

```
~/public_html/mantis/
~/public_html/phpmyadmin/
```

The application used to be accessed as:

```
www.mysite.com/beta/
```

And the others as:

```
www.mysite.com/mantis
www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin
```

We've had to make certain changes in our application and need to shift the application from /beta/ to / (ie the document root).

I'm not comfortable with having mantis, phpmyadmin as subfolders in public_html - I'm afraid they may be accidentally deleted / tampered by me / other admins.

How can I setup my httpd.conf so that I can continue accessing my mantis and phpmyadmin as:

```
www.mysite.com/mantis
www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin
```

as well as keep the "application" at:

```
www.mysite.com
```

?

---

My current httpd.conf reads as:

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
    ServerAlias MYSITE.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName MYSITE.com
    UseCanonicalName On

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
...
```

Comment: Is this a shared host, or do you have full control of the config?

Comment: @SmallClanger - Hi. I have full control of the system. Please see added httpd.conf details as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to keep them in folders under the main domain, or can you put them on subdomains?

You can keep the application, mantis and phpmyadmin in separate folders, set up 3 virtual domains for each of them, eg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName MYSITE.com
    ServerAlias www.MYSITE.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html
#etc

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.MYSITE.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
#etc

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mantis.MYSITE.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mantis
#etc
```

So application straight into public_html, phpmyadmin into /var/www/html/phpmyadmin, and mantis into /var/www/html/mantis.

Then just set up the additional DNS and access the sites with:
www.mysite.com
phpmyadmin.mysite.com
mantis.mysite.com

Comment: thanks @Demelziraptor (nice name btw) - i think i have to end up doing that, but i've already got the mantis bugs referenced like: www.mysite.com/mantis/(blahblah)

Comment: thanks Dzr - interestingly, the order mattered a lot...!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a rewrite rule in .htaccess, something like
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?!mantis)(?!phpmyadmin)(.*)$ beta/$1 [L]
```

(That will redirect every request to the /beta/ subfolder unless it starts in ether mantis or phpmyadmin, also it was done from memory so if you get a syntax error it's just my ineptness at regular expressions)

Comment: sorry, i'm a bit confused... where should my application be now? I'm not sure if you read my question correctly, I'm _moving_ it from public_html/beta/ to public_html/

Comment: @matt74tm You don't need to move the files for this to work, you can keep the application in /beta/, while the public URL is still /. That solves your problem of people accidentally deleting stuff (They would all be in the beta directory) without having to do some complicated directory configs/permissions to get everything working

Comment: Hi. Please see added httpd.conf details - what do i need to change in my current system to make it work as desired?

Comment: @matt74tm Add those rewrite rules just after the last 'RewriteRule' in your httpd.conf (Where the ... is in the post, just put them there)